# CSS: display page on 4k screen the same as on FHD

Tags: html, css

is there any trick that a website gets rendered the same way like on a FHD screens so that it simulates that it has 1080px?

I tried it with the viewport meta tag but it did not work out.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1080, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I take it you don't mean HiDPI 4K displays (which should already display your page at 1080p in CSS pixels)?

Comment: "I tried it with the viewport meta tag but it did not work out." What did you try? Post some code.

Comment: @Marko <meta name="viewport" content="width=1080, initial-scale=1">

Comment: @BlotClock on TV screens

Answer (score -3):

Just detect the screen if it's 4k, e.g. >= 3000px then set the zoom property to 200%

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 3000px) {
  html {
    zoom: 200%
  }
}
```